# Check if URL is live usint TOR

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to use vb.net to check if a URL exists using TOR browser?

I know this can easily be achieved using a browser control for clear websites.

Comment: [Tor.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1072864/Tor-NET-A-managed-Tor-network-library).

Comment: Looks interesting, but can't see much examples in terms of handling 404s etc... how would I see if a url is active?

Comment: That something you should read it from the `response` stream. Dig [deeper](https://github.com/sharpbrowser/Tor.NET) in the source code.